# Последовательность передачи команд через COM-порт

Tags: c#, com-порт

Работаю с устройством через COM-порт. Отправка команды ведется обычным методом через запись

```
_port.Write("ATH0 \r\n"); // установка режима ожидания
```

чтение производится в асинхронном режиме

```
private void _port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var sp = (SerialPort) sender;
    var data = new byte[sp.BytesToRead];
    sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    var inData = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);

    if (inData.Length > 0)
        Dispatcher.Invoke(RType == 0 ? new dlgAddRes(Upg) : UpgR, inData); 
}
```

Upg - процедура, вносящая изменения в UI интерфейс приложения.

Проблема заключается в том, что следующую команду можно посылать только ПОСЛЕ получения ответа на предыдущую (и некоторого таймаута).

Как это лучше всего сделать, учитывая асинхронный режим работы?

Comment: Не вижу асинхронности. Асинхронность- это когда вы отправили устройству команду, а сами занимаетесь другими действиями. Устройство выполнило задачу, вы вернулись в метод и продолжили выполнение. Ну или в старом стиле это делалось через BeginInvoke, EndInvoke. P.S Пусть кто-нибудь поправить меня, если я не прав.

Comment: Что если вам на уровне класса завести булеву переменную isResponsed. Перед отправкой очередной команды, вы ее проверяете. Если она false, то ждете пока не станет true. Отправляете сообщение на порт и переводите поле в false. В теории работать должно.

Comment: @iluxa1810 все так, кроме того что ждать булеву переменную нехорошо. Надо или класть команды в очередь, или использовать TaskCompletionSource для настоящей асинхронности.

Comment: Стоит прояснить, что с командами - есть готовый список, который нужно выполнить по мере подтверждения предыдущих? Или команды формируются по ходу дела в зависимости от ответов?

Comment: Да,есть готовый список. Но бывает необходимо выбрать команду в зависимости от результата предыдущей